# How to convert GeoJSON to NetworkX graph

Tags: python, gis, networkx, geojson

I have a GeoJSON file that records a city's roads geocodes and their attributes. Sample looks like this

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection", "features": [
{"type":"Feature","geometry":
{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[lat1, long1],[lat2, long2],[lat3, long3]]},
"properties":{"ROUTE_TYPE":,"TOTAL_LANE":,"AADT":}}}}
```

In this case, how can I convert such JSON to a networkX graph? 
Ideally a DiGraph (I do notice that direction information is not indicted in the JSON at all. I am fine with assuming all links are bidirectional.)

Comment: Your JSON sample is not valid/well formed. Could you fix that please?

Answer (score 2):

This question is similar to the following question on GIS stackexchange: [Retrieving OpenStreetMap data with Python using GeoJSON geometry as boundary](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/396224/retrieving-openstreetmap-data-with-python-using-geojson-geometry-as-boundary) and its [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/396252).

The main ingredients you need are the following:

1. [`geopandas`](https://geopandas.org) to parse the `geojson` into a `GeoDataFrame` with [`read_file`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.read_file.html)
2. [`OSMnx`](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to transform the `GeoDataFrame` into a `networkx.MultiDiGraph` using [`osmnx.utils_graph.graph_from_gdfs`](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.utils_graph.graph_from_gdfs)

Alternatively, you could use `ignore_geometry=True`in the first step and use [`nx.from_pandas_edgelist`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist.html)